# VBA Data extraction

Tags: excel, vba

I am attempting to populate a database using data from excel(originally from a PDF). The data exists in excel in one column, e.g

```
Event Date:
02/02/02
Location:
UK
Event:
Fire
Event Date:
03/03/03
Location:
US
Cause:
Hurricane
```

I have created a virtual matrix to hold the data, then from that I then search through and extract the sought after info.

However, the problem arises because not all the data entries follow the same format.

So when populating the database it goes something like this.

```
Date...................Location.................Cause..................Event 
02/02/02.............UK.........................Hurricane..............Fire
03/03/03.............US.........................Flood...................Fire
04/04/04.............France..............................................Structural Damage
05/05/05.............Germany............................................Fire
```

However, the information does not correspond to the correct data etc as it simply fills from the top down.

I need the information to be presented in a manner like this;

```
Date.............Location........Cause......................Event
02/02/02........UK..........................................Fire
03/03/03........US...............Hurricane..................Fire
04/04/04........France..........Flood.......................Structural Damage
05/05/05........Germany......................................Fire
```

I have tried extracting the data using my code below but have only managed to extract the information without keeping it in the required order. Is there a better way to assign the data into an array while extracting?

My current code:

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetBeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)

Dim pd(100000, 100)
Dim rpd(10000, 100)
Dim c As Integer
Dim npd As Variant

rpd(1, 1) = "Loss Number"
rpd(1, 2) = "Event Date"
rpd(1, 3) = "Country"
rpd(1, 4) = "Location"
rpd(1, 5) = "Event"
rpd(1, 6) = "Cause"
rpd(1, 7) = "Unit Type"
rpd(1, 8) = "Equipment Type"
rpd(1, 9) = "Materials"
rpd(1, 10) = "Fatalities"
rpd(1, 11) = "Injuries"
rpd(1, 12) = "Duration"
rpd(1, 13) = "Evacuated"
rpd(1, 14) = "Plant Status"
rpd(1, 15) = "Interruption"
rpd(1, 16) = "Description"


c = 1
cr = 1
npd = 1

LastRow = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("PDF Input Sheet").UsedRange.Rows.count
Lastcol = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("PDF Input Sheet").UsedRange.Columns.count

'Collect data for virtual matrix
Do Until npd = LastRow
    For c = 1 To Lastcol
        pd(npd, c) = Sheets("PDF Input Sheet").Cells(npd, c)
    Next c
    npd = npd + 1
Loop

'Extract loss number data
R = 1
cr = 1

Do Until R = npd
If pd(R, 1) = "Loss Number:" Then
    If pd(R + 1, 1) <> "" Then LossNumber = pd(R + 1, 1)

    cr = cr + 1

    rpd(cr, 1) = LossNumber

End If

R = R + 1

Loop

'Extract event date information
R = 1
cr = 1

Do Until R = npd
If pd(R, 1) = "Event Date:" Then
    If pd(R + 1, 1) <> "" Then EveDate = pd(R + 1, 1)

    cr = cr + 1

    rpd(cr, 2) = EveDate

End If

R = R + 1

Loop

'Extract country data
R = 1
cr = 1

Do Until R = npd
If pd(R, 1) = "Country:" Then
    If pd(R + 1, 1) <> "" Then Country = pd(R + 1, 1)

    cr = cr + 1

    rpd(cr, 3) = Country

End If

R = R + 1

Loop

'Extract location data
R = 1
cr = 1

Do Until R = npd
If pd(R, 1) = "Location:" Then
    If pd(R + 1, 1) <> "" Then Location = pd(R + 1, 1)

    cr = cr + 1

    rpd(cr, 4) = Location

End If

R = R + 1

Loop

'Extract event data
R = 1
cr = 1

Do Until R = npd

If pd(R, 1) = "Event:" Then
    If pd(R + 1, 1) <> "" Then Even = pd(R + 1, 1)

    cr = cr + 1

    rpd(cr, 5) = Even


End If

R = R + 1

Loop





Sheets("Accident Database").Activate
Sheets("Accident Database").Columns("A:IV").ClearContents
For R = 1 To 200
    For c = 1 To 16
    Sheets("Accident Database").Cells(R, c) = rpd(R, c)
    Next c
Next R

'Range("A1:IV4000").Sort _
'Key1:=Range("B1"), Header:=xlYes

Sheets("Accident Database").Columns("A:IV").AutoFit




End Sub
```

Comment: While one has to read 5 minutes before figuring what is the question, you won't get many answers. Put your question (the sentence ending with "?") at the beginning, or put it in **bold**, remove every "I wonder" and other useless words, and check the help on formatting. Good luck ;-)

Comment: *How should I go about extracting the data in the desired format?*  Try something. Does it work? If not, refine and try again. If you have *specific questions* or encounter runtime errors/problems, you'll get more help here than you will with a general "How should I X...?" question.  Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Not an answer, but I'd like to point out that you don't need loops to read a range into an array !

```
 dim r() as variant
 r = range(cells(firstRow, firstCol) , cells((lastRow, lastCol))
 'or
 r = range("B2:f20")
```

will do the trick, and much faster.